# how to convert filepath to url in reactjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, reactjs, d3.js

I'm trying to modify my code to load a Json file from an URL rather than to use from a local file. Can anyone please explain me how to resolve this issue

```
const TAXONOMY_DATA = require(../../assets/chord.json);

//for filters**
class AddRemoveSelection extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            selectedOptions: []
        }
    }

    handleDeselect = (deselectedOptions) => {
        var selectedOptions = this.state.selectedOptions.slice()
        deselectedOptions.forEach(option => {
            selectedOptions.splice(selectedOptions.indexOf(option), 1)
        })
        this.setState({ selectedOptions })
        this.props.onChange(selectedOptions)
    }

    handleSelect = (selectedOptions) => {
        selectedOptions.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id)
        this.setState({ selectedOptions })
        this.props.onChange(selectedOptions)
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (nextProps.options !== this.props.options) {
            this.setState({ selectedOptions: nextProps.options });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { selectedOptions } = this.state
        const { options, type } = this.props

        return <div className="row mt-20">
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <FilteredMultiSelect
                    placeholder={`Select ${type}`}
                    buttonText="Add"
                    classNames={{
                        filter: 'form-control',
                        select: 'form-control',
                        button: 'btn btn btn-block btn-default',
                        buttonActive: 'btn btn btn-block btn-primary',
                    }}
                    onChange={this.handleSelect}
                    options={options}
                    selectedOptions={selectedOptions}
                    textProp="name"
                    valueProp="id"
                />
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-6">
                <FilteredMultiSelect
                    placeholder={`Visible ${type}`}
                    buttonText="Delete"
                    classNames={{
                        filter: 'form-control',
                        select: 'form-control',
                        button: 'btn btn btn-block btn-default',
                        buttonActive: 'btn btn btn-block btn-danger'
                    }}
                    onChange={this.handleDeselect}
                    options={selectedOptions}
                    textProp="name"
                    valueProp="id"
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}


export default class ChordFinal extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            master: {},
            filterKeyword: {},
            filterTaxonomy: {},
            tooltip: {},
            pFormat: d3.format(".1%"),
            qFormat: d3.format(",.0f"),

            rankList: [],
            categoryList: [],
            selectedRank: "",
            selectedCategory: "",

            keywordsOptions: [],
            selectedKeywordsOptions: [],
            taxonomyOptions: [],
            selectedTaxonomyOptions: [],
        };

        this.importJSON = this.importJSON.bind(this);
        this.addFilter = this.addFilter.bind(this);
        this.updateChart = this.updateChart.bind(this);
        this.updateTooltip = this.updateTooltip.bind(this);
        this.reset = this.reset.bind(this);
        this.setFilters = this.setFilters.bind(this);
    }

    toggleVisibility = () => this.setState({ visible: !this.state.visible })

    updateTooltip = (data) => {
        console.log(data);

        this.setState({
            tooltip: data
        });
    };



    addFilter = (name) => {
        let filters = this.state.filters;
        filters[name] = {
            name: name,
            hide: true
        };
        this.setState({
            hasFilters: true,
            filters: filters
        });
        this.update()
    };

    // 1 - parse the data to get the list of ranks and categories
    importJSON() {

        // temporary dictionaries
        const ranks = {}
        const categories = {}
        const master = {}
        const rankList = []
        const categoryList = []

        TAXONOMY_DATA.fulldata.forEach(d => {
            const rank = d.taxonomyRank;
            const keyword = d.keywordCategory;

            ranks[rank] = true;
            categories[keyword] = true;
            if (!master[rank]) {
                master[rank] = {}
            }
            if (!master[rank][keyword]) {
                master[rank][keyword] = []
            }
            master[rank][keyword].push(d);
        })

        // add ranks/categories to list
        for (let key in ranks) {
            if (ranks.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                rankList.push(key);
            }
        }

        for (let key in categories) {
            if (categories.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                categoryList.push(key);
            }
        }
        console.log('rankList', rankList)
        console.log('categoryList', categoryList)
        console.log('master', master)

        this.setState({
            rankList,
            categoryList,
            master,

            selectedRank: "superfamily",
            selectedCategory: "Biological process",
        }, () => {
            this.updateList()
        });
    }

    // create taxonomy/keyword list
    updateList() {
        // temporary dictionary
        const keywords = {}
        const taxonomies = {}
        const { master, selectedRank, selectedCategory } = this.state
        console.log(`master[${selectedRank}][${selectedCategory}]`)

        if (master && master[selectedRank] && master[selectedRank][selectedCategory]) {
            console.log(`master[${selectedRank}][${selectedCategory}]`, master[selectedRank][selectedCategory])
            master[selectedRank][selectedCategory].forEach(d => {
                keywords[d.keywordId] = d.keywordName;
                taxonomies[d.taxId] = d.taxonomyName;
            })

            const keywordsOptions = [];
            const taxonomyOptions = [];

            // creates keyword list
            for (let key in keywords) {
                if (keywords.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    keywordsOptions.push({ id: key, name: keywords[key] });
                }
            }

            // creates taxonomy list
            for (let key in taxonomies) {
                if (taxonomies.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    taxonomyOptions.push({ id: key, name: taxonomies[key] });
                }
            }

            const selectedKeywordsOptions = keywordsOptions.slice();
            const selectedTaxonomyOptions = taxonomyOptions.slice();

            this.setState({
                keywordsOptions,
                selectedKeywordsOptions,
                taxonomyOptions,
                selectedTaxonomyOptions,

                filterKeyword: keywords,
                filterTaxonomy: taxonomies,
            }, () => {
                this.updateChart();
            });
        }
    }

    updateChart() {
        const { master, selectedRank, selectedCategory, filterKeyword, filterTaxonomy } = this.state;
        const data = master[selectedRank][selectedCategory];
        if (data) {
            this.child.drawChords(data.filter(d => (filterKeyword[d.keywordId] && filterTaxonomy[d.taxId])));
        }
    };

    setFilters(item, input) {
        let state = this.state;
        state.filters[item.name] = {
            name: item.name,
            hide: input.target.checked
        }
        this.setState({
            filters: state.filters
        });
        this.update(state);
    }

    reset() {
        let state = this.state;
        if (Object.keys(state.filters).length > 0 && state.hasFilters {
            state.filters = {};
            state.hasFilters = false;
            this.setState({
                filters: {},
                hasFilters: false
            });
            this.updateChart();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isComponentMount: true });

        this.importJSON();
    }

    render =() => {
        let state = this.state;
        const { visible, rankList, categoryList, selectedRank, selectedCategory } = this.state

        return <div>
            <Sidebar.Pushable as={Segment}>
              <Button onClick={this.toggleVisibility} icon className="navbar-toggle">
                <Icon name="align justify"/>
              </Button>
              <Sidebar as={Menu} animation="overlay" width="very wide" direction="right" visible={visible} icon="labeled" vertical inverted>
                <Icon className="close" size="large" onClick={this.toggleVisibility} />
                <div className="row mt-50" />
                <div className="row mt-20">
                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <Dropdown placeholder="Select Rank" selection value={selectedRank} options={rankList.map(
                        item => ({ key: item, text: item, value: item })
                      )} onChange={(e, data) => {
                        this.setState(
                          { selectedRank: data.value },
                          () => {
                            this.updateList();
                          }
                        );
                      }} />
                  </div>
                  <div className="col-sm-6">
                    <Dropdown placeholder="Select Category" selection value={selectedCategory} options={categoryList.map(
                        item => ({ key: item, text: item, value: item })
                      )} onChange={(e, data) => {
                        this.setState(
                          { selectedCategory: data.value },
                          () => {
                            this.updateList();
                          }
                        );
                      }} />
                  </div>
                </div>
                <AddRemoveSelection type="Taxonomy" options={this.state.taxonomyOptions} onChange={selectedTaxonomyOptions
{
                    this.setState({ selectedTaxonomyOptions });
                  }} />
                <br />
                <AddRemoveSelection type="Keywords" options={this.state.keywordsOptions} onChange={selectedKeywordsOptions
{
                    this.setState({ selectedKeywordsOptions });
                  }} />
                <div className="row mt-20">
                  <div className="col-sm-12 text-left">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary" id="submit" onClick={this.toggleVisibility}>
                      Submit
                    </button>
                    <button className="btn btn-danger"  id="reset" onClick={this.reset}>
                      Reset
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </Sidebar>
              <Sidebar.Pusher>
                <Segment basic>
                  <div className="row" style={{ position: "relative" }}>
                    <div className="large-8 small-12" role="content">
                      <article style={{ width: 800, height: 800 }} id="chord">
                        {state.isComponentMount ? 
                            <Chord updateTooltip={this.updateTooltip} addFilter={this.addFilter} onRef={ref => (this.child = ref)} filters={state.filters} />
                        : null}
                      </article>
                    </div>
                    <fieldset id="tooltip" placement="top" className="row">
                      <div className="small-6 small-12 ">
                        <h6>
                          Taxonomy Name: {state.tooltip.tname} <br /> Keyword Name: {state.tooltip.kname} <br /> Taxonomy ID: {state.tooltip.tid} <br /> Keyword Visibility: {state.tooltip.kwVizState} <br /> Taxonomy Visibility: {state.tooltip.taxVizState} <br /> Keyword ID: {state.tooltip.kid} <br /> Spect Count: {state.tooltip.tvalue}{" "}
                        </h6>
                      </div>
                    </fieldset>
                  </div>
                </Segment>
              </Sidebar.Pusher>
            </Sidebar.Pushable>
          </div>;
    }
}




    // 1 - parse the data to get the list of ranks and categories
    importJSON() {

        // temporary dictionaries
        const ranks = {}
        const categories = {}

        const master = {}
        const rankList = []
        const categoryList = []


          //to be placed for fullDataChord API fetch once it'S available
        //    d3.json('https://bitbucket.org/rohitkalva/viz/raw/11e7059eceaf571b12bf97d348cc157e5bf11fa3/fulldata.json')


        TAXONOMY_DATA.fulldata.forEach(d => {
            const rank = d.taxonomyRank;
            const keyword = d.keywordCategory;

            ranks[rank] = true;
            categories[keyword] = true;
            if (!master[rank]) {
                master[rank] = {}
            }
            if (!master[rank][keyword]) {
                master[rank][keyword] = []
            }
            master[rank][keyword].push(d);
        })


        // add ranks/categories to list
        for (let key in ranks) {
            if (ranks.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                rankList.push(key);
            }
        }

        for (let key in categories) {
            if (categories.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                categoryList.push(key);
            }
        }
        console.log('rankList', rankList)
        console.log('categoryList', categoryList)
        console.log('master', master)

        this.setState({
            rankList,
            categoryList,
            master,
            // selectedRank: rankList[0],
            // selectedCategory: categoryList[0],
            selectedRank: "superfamily",
            selectedCategory: "Biological process",
        }, () => {
            this.updateList()
        });
    }

    // create taxonomy/keyword list
    updateList() {
        // temporary dictionary
        const keywords = {}
        const taxonomies = {}
        const { master, selectedRank, selectedCategory } = this.state
        console.log(`master[${selectedRank}][${selectedCategory}]`)

        if (master && master[selectedRank] && master[selectedRank][selectedCategory]) {
            console.log(`master[${selectedRank}][${selectedCategory}]`, master[selectedRank][selectedCategory])
            master[selectedRank][selectedCategory].forEach(d => {
                keywords[d.keywordId] = d.keywordName;
                taxonomies[d.taxId] = d.taxonomyName;
            })

            const keywordsOptions = [];
            const taxonomyOptions = [];

            // creates keyword list
            for (let key in keywords) {
                if (keywords.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    keywordsOptions.push({ id: key, name: keywords[key] });
                }
            }

            // creates taxonomy list
            for (let key in taxonomies) {
                if (taxonomies.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                    taxonomyOptions.push({ id: key, name: taxonomies[key] });
                }
            }

            const selectedKeywordsOptions = keywordsOptions.slice();
            const selectedTaxonomyOptions = taxonomyOptions.slice();

            this.setState({
                keywordsOptions,
                selectedKeywordsOptions,
                taxonomyOptions,
                selectedTaxonomyOptions,

                filterKeyword: keywords,
                filterTaxonomy: taxonomies,
            }, () => {
                this.updateChart();
            });
        }

    }




    updateChart() {
        const { master, selectedRank, selectedCategory, filterKeyword, filterTaxonomy } = this.state;
        const data = master[selectedRank][selectedCategory];
        if (data) {
            this.child.drawChords(data.filter(d => (filterKeyword[d.keywordId] && filterTaxonomy[d.taxId])));
        }
    };

    setFilters(item, input) {
        let state = this.state;
        state.filters[item.name] = {
            name: item.name,
            hide: input.target.checked
        }
        this.setState({
            filters: state.filters
        });
        this.update(state);
    }

    reset() {
        let state = this.state;
        if (Object.keys(state.filters).length > 0 && state.hasFilters) {
            state.filters = {};
            state.hasFilters = false;
            this.setState({
                filters: {},
                hasFilters: false
            });
            this.updateChart();
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState({ isComponentMount: true });

        this.importJSON();
    }
```

Comment: Can you please edit your question. It's not readable like that. It's useless to copy paste all your code. Just share the code with your issue

Comment: thanks for the edit :) @vishal Chhodwani...

Comment: @عبداللهيوسفعزام My Pleasure :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `require` at the beginning,

```
const TAXONOMY_DATA = require(../../assets/chord.json);
```

Utilize [fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        selectedOptions: [],
        TAXONOMY_DATA: null 
    }
}


importJSON() {

    const ranks = {}
    const categories = {}
    const master = {}
    const rankList = []
    const categoryList = []

    fetch("https://.../chord.json")
        .then( (response) => {
            return response.json() 
        })   
        .then( (json) => {
            this.setState({
                TAXONOMY_DATA: json
            }, ()=> {
                this.state.TAXONOMY_DATA.fulldata.forEach(d => {
                    const rank = d.taxonomyRank;
                    const keyword = d.keywordCategory;

                    ranks[rank] = true;
                    categories[keyword] = true;
                    if (!master[rank]) {
                        master[rank] = {}
                    }
                    if (!master[rank][keyword]) {
                        master[rank][keyword] = []
                    }
                    master[rank][keyword].push(d);

                     ...

                    this.setState({
                        rankList,
                        categoryList,
                        master,
                        selectedRank: "superfamily",
                        selectedCategory: "Biological process",
                    }, () => {
                        this.updateList()
                    });
            });
        });

}
```

And because you deploy `importJSON` in `componentDidMount()`, which means you ask for data after all of the element have been rendered once. This would cause problem cause you have many value assignment in `importJSON` and you don't have those values when the first rendering, you need make sure `this.state.TAXONOMY_DATA` have been settled and then assigned value by

```
render =() => {
    ...
    if(this.state.TAXONOMY_DATA) {
        const { visible, rankList, categoryList, selectedRank, selectedCategory } = this.state`
        return (<div>...</div>)
    } else {
        return null;
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: yes. Is it possible to render the filtered-multiSelect options alphabetically?

Comment: @عبداللهيوسفعزام,  I'm glad it's helpful. Welcome to the community, maybe you could 'accept' the answer matching the question inquired. Btw, alphabetically is possible, but it depends on which value of key in your object you want to sort on, it needs more detailed informations and I believe it worths another question and discussion, and someone more experienced really could answer it promptly if you provide clear informations.

Answer (score 1):

React doesn't mind how you do API(URL) call. you can choose whatever kind of AJAX library you like for this task. The simplest way is this.

```
  importJSON() {

        const ranks = {}
        const categories = {}
        const master = {}
        const rankList = []
        const categoryList = []

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', '/my/url', true);
        request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {

          this.state({
                    TAXONOMY_DATA: xhttp.responseText
                }, ()=> {
                    this.state.TAXONOMY_DATA.fulldata.forEach(d => {
                    const rank = d.taxonomyRank;
                    const keyword = d.keywordCategory;

                    ranks[rank] = true;
                    categories[keyword] = true;
                    if (!master[rank]) {
                        master[rank] = {}
                    }
                    if (!master[rank][keyword]) {
                        master[rank][keyword] = []
                    }
                    master[rank][keyword].push(d);
                });
            });

        }
    };
        request.send();
 // add ranks/categories to list
        for (let key in ranks) {
            if (ranks.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                rankList.push(key);
            }
        }

        for (let key in categories) {
            if (categories.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                categoryList.push(key);
            }
        }
        console.log('rankList', rankList)
        console.log('categoryList', categoryList)
        console.log('master', master)

        this.setState({
            rankList,
            categoryList,
            master,

            selectedRank: "superfamily",
            selectedCategory: "Biological process",
        }, () => {
            this.updateList()
        });
    }
```

Comment: when data is loaded from a URL in console it shows: rankList =Array(0)
categoryList =Array(0)
master: {}; master: [superfamily][Biological process]
But, when data is loaded from FILE in console it shows: rankList: Array(28); categoryList Array(10); master[superfamily][Biological process]:  Array(62).